# Look up the class a method was delegated to? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

If I use `delegate :Mayfield, to: :user`

What can I call on :Mayfield to see it was delegated to the :user class?

SOLUTION:
NOT POSSIBLE

Comment: Do you want to do this for testing purposes or for reflection while the actual application is running?

Comment: I'm not quite able to answer your question, but if you have a look at the source code, maybe that could help? https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb

Comment: @milgner while the application is running. I have a form object with multiple models and using simple_form, it uses the :type_for_attribute, :has_attribute? but I need to figure a way to dynamically delegate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BKSpurgeon already pointed out, the [implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb#L218) of the `delegate` method doesn't do anything but create a method that invokes the given method on an object.

As such, there is no "dynamic" delegation: just implement a regular method of the same name and have it return whatever value you need.

```
def Mayfield
  case some_attribute_value
  when 'foo' then user.Mayfield
  when 'bar' then something_else.Mayfield
  end
end
```

Comment: Where are the created method stored? As I would like to look up the  method to find the class its delegated to? I have a large number of attributes delegated and it would be easier to access the information than have to worry about updating the case statement after every change in delegation.

Comment: They're just regular methods. The statement in your question would result in the code `def Mayfield; user.Mayfield; end` (can't format it properly here). It's just the same as if you'd written it out yourself, except it can also do `nil` checks.

Comment: ok, got it, so there is no way to reverse it because it's just a normal method. thanks